# Cross server file upload: limits and method?

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to build a Web app scenario, let's say:
 I'm using a **server A** (Linux Apache Shared Hosting, so no access to php.ini),
the php.ini being:

```
max_execution_time  120
max_file_uploads    20
max_input_nesting_level 64
max_input_time  60
max_input_vars  2000
memory_limit    128M
open_basedir    no value
output_buffering    4096
output_handler  no value
post_max_size   64M
```

**Server A** would host a website with an HTML form to upload files (probably with PHP `move_uploaded_file` , `ftp_put` or ajax `XMLHttpRequest`) to a **server B** (Linux Apache Dedicated server with editable php.ini).

> My goal is to allow users to upload large files from the HTML form on **server A** to a **server B** directory

- Question 1: Would the limits of **server A** be a problem?
- Question 2: Which file upload method would you go for in this case?

Thanks so much for your time

Comment: Why not just put the forms submit script on server b? <form method="post" action="http://url.to.serverb/submit.php">

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Jesper, Do you think the server A max_execution_time will not break the upload that way? sorry I'm a bit confused/confusing

Comment: If you submit directly to sever b from html the request will never even touch server a, the clients browser will connect directly to server b to deliver the post data, so there should not be any issues. If you wanted to you could create a form on your page like this `<form method="post" action="http://www.google.com"><input type="text" name="q"/><input type="submit" value="search"></form>` that would do a search on google and your server would never see the data.

Comment: thanks so much to help clarify! and help cooling my head! haha, have a nice week end!